# How to keep repeating the input statement?

Tags: python, input

I am new to Python and I have been trying to develop a chatbot. Here is the code

```
print("Hi! I am AUGbot")
x = input()
if x == "hi":
    print("Hello!")
elif x == "hello":
    print("Hi!")
elif x == "how are you":
    print("I am fine! How are you?")
elif x == "i am fine":
    print("Nice!")
elif x == "i am not fine":
    print("Oh, Sorry to know that")
else:
    print("I am not sure I understand")
```

After the code is executed, It ends. How can I keep the input statement running even after the user gives the input? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of [loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm)? Have you tried using them?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am kinda new to Python so I do not understand the concept of the while loops. Will you be able to help me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Complete code:

```
print("Hi! I am Jarvis.Let me know, how i can assist you?")
while True:
    user_input = input("Leave Your Message...")
    if user_input == "hi":
        print("Hello")
    elif user_input == "hello":
        print("Hi")
    elif user_input == "how are you":
        print("I am fine! How are you?")
    elif user_input == "i am fine":
        print("Nice!")
    elif user_input == "i am not fine":
        print("Oh, Sorry to know that")
    elif user_input == "exit":
        print("Thank you!")
        break
    else:
        print("I am not sure I understand!Type Again")
```